# How to summarize the result from two tables?

Tags: sql

```
SupplierId NetAmt
1          400
2          400
3          300
2          200

SupplierId RecdAmt
2          200
2          200
2          200
```

Expectect result:

```
1   400
3   300
```

First Table is Inward Table and Second Table is Payment Table when i do payment to supplier who's payment done fully should not show again

Comment: what is the logic to get the output.. Please elaborate the question

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
select SupplierId , NetAmt from table1 
where SupplierId  not in (select SupplierId from table2)
```

or

you can also try this

```
SELECT SupplierId , NetAmt
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.SupplierId = t2.SupplierId 
WHERE t2.SupplierId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to get the balance per supplier

```
SELECT ISNULL(NetTable.SupID, RecTable.SupID) AS SupID, (ISNULL(NetTable.TotalNet,0) - ISNULL(RecTable.TotalRec,0)) AS BalAmt
FROM (SELECT SupID, SUM(NetAmt) AS TotalNet FROM Table_1 GROUP BY SupID) AS NetTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT SupID, SUM(RecAmt) AS TotalRec FROM Table_2 GROUP BY SupID) AS RecTable
ON NetTable.SupID = RecTable.SupID
WHERE NetTable.TotalNet <> RecTable.TotalRec
```

Need to GROUP BY supplier each table separately & JOIN the summaries.